# Standalone Exq in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

There's a way to run `exq` as standalone app: https://github.com/akira/exq#standalone-exq. But the thing is that I don't really understand how to make it work. If `exq` is added as dependency to my phoenix app it's already running when I run my application. I can enqueue jobs and they're running. So my question is how to not run it alongside with my application but run it as separate app? (e.g so it's possible to run it on separate worker on Heroku).

Comment: I think you just need to remove `:exq` from the applications list in `mix.exs`?

Comment: When I do that (well, not exactly that, I was trying to add `runtime: false` to exq entry in `deps`) I can't enqueue jobs anymore. I get `** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to run Exq in the Phoenix app, with ability to enqueue, but not have it run the jobs in that instance?

There's two options:

1) You can set Exq to only start in Enqueuer mode. With this, you can leave it in the mix.exs.  To do this, change the configs:

```
config :exq,
    ...
    mode: :enqueuer,
    ...
```

You can then Enqueue with:

`Exq.enqueue(Exq.Enqueuer, "default", HelloWorker, [])`

2) You can turn off the queues so that there are no queues being listened to:

```
config :exq,
    ...
    queues: [],
    ...
```

You can use usual way of enqueuing `Exq.enqueue(Exq, "default", HelloWorker, [])`

Comment: awesome, that's exactly what I need. and thank for the lib!

Comment: Hi @alex-k !  Is this answer out of date per chance, or is there an option that's missing now?  I'm following these and I'm not getting an error, log, or anything (whereas before I was getting the error mentioned above by Vasiliy)